# Exclude .env directory from flake8 tests?

Tags: python, django, flake8

## Problem

I'm getting thousands of flake8 errors stemming from my local .env. An example of some of the error messages:

```
./env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyparsing.py:3848:80: E501 line too long (85 > 79 characters)
./env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyparsing.py:3848:84: E202 whitespace before ')'
./env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyparsing.py:3855:51: E201 whitespace after '('
./env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyparsing.py:3855:65: E202 whitespace before ')'
./env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyparsing.py:3858:50: E201 whitespace after '('
./env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyparsing.py:3858:78: E202 whitespace before ')'
./env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyparsing.py:3861:31: E231 missing whitespace after ','
./env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyparsing.py:3865:1: W293 blank line contains whitespace
./env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyparsing.py:3866:1: E302 expected 2 blank lines, found 1
```

My directory looks like this:

[image]

My flake8 file looks like this:

```
[flake8]
exclude =
    migrations,
    __pycache__,
    manage.py,
    settings.py,
```

## Question

How can I add my env file contents to the exclude list in flake8?

## What I've tried

I've tried adding:

```
  env,
./env,
```

I've tried taking off commas and adding:

```
[flake8]
exclude =
    migrations
    __pycache__
    manage.py
    settings.py
    env
    .env
    ./env
    env/
    .env/
```

Running flake8 --exclude migrations,**pycache**,manage.py,settings.py,env 
returns:

```
./app/core/models.py:7:80: E501 line too long (93 > 79 characters)
./app/core/models.py:13:66: E225 missing whitespace around operator
./app/core/models.py:13:80: E501 line too long (103 > 79 characters)
./app/core/admin.py:10:1: W293 blank line contains whitespace
./app/core/admin.py:11:1: W293 blank line contains whitespace
./app/core/admin.py:13:1: W293 blank line contains whitespace
./app/core/tests/test_commands.py:23:47: W292 no newline at end of file
./app/core/management/commands/wait_for_db.py:21:69: W292 no newline at end of file
./app/project/urls.py:23:2: W292 no newline at end of file
./app/inventory/serializers.py:4:1: E302 expected 2 blank lines, found 1
./app/inventory/serializers.py:8:1: W391 blank line at end of file
./app/inventory/urls.py:5:70: W291 trailing whitespace
./app/inventory/urls.py:7:26: W292 no newline at end of file
./app/inventory/views.py:1:1: F401 'rest_framework.response.Response' imported but unused
./app/inventory/views.py:7:1: E302 expected 2 blank lines, found 1
./app/inventory/views.py:11:1: W293 blank line contains whitespace
./app/inventory/views.py:12:5: E303 too many blank lines (2)
./app/inventory/views.py:36:43: W292 no newline at end of file
./app/inventory/tests/test_api.py:2:1: F401 'django.urls.reverse' imported but unused
./app/inventory/tests/test_api.py:7:1: W293 blank line contains whitespace
./app/inventory/tests/test_api.py:9:8: E111 indentation is not a multiple of four
./app/inventory/tests/test_api.py:10:8: E111 indentation is not a multiple of four
./app/inventory/tests/test_api.py:10:40: W291 trailing whitespace
./app/inventory/tests/test_api.py:11:1: W293 blank line contains whitespace
./app/inventory/tests/test_api.py:12:8: E111 indentation is not a multiple of four
./app/inventory/tests/test_api.py:13:8: E111 indentation is not a multiple of four
./app/inventory/tests/test_api.py:18:41: W291 trailing whitespace
./app/inventory/tests/test_api.py:19:1: W293 blank line contains whitespace
./app/inventory/tests/test_api.py:25:37: W291 trailing whitespace
./app/inventory/tests/test_api.py:26:41: W291 trailing whitespace
./app/inventory/tests/test_api.py:27:1: W293 blank line contains whitespace
./app/inventory/tests/test_api.py:31:1: W391 blank line at end of file
./app/inventory/tests/test_api.py:31:1: W293 blank line contains whitespace
```

Comment: Have you tried using `env`? Is the result the same?

Comment: Thanks Lucus but I have. I will update the question to include this

Comment: or rather `.env/` ?

Comment: I have tried this just now too. I'll add that to the things tried.

Comment: Can you try providing the exclude patterns on the command line?
`flake8 --exclude migrations,__pycache__,manage.py,settings.py,env`

Comment: Hi Lucus, I've just done that and updated the question

Comment: It looks like it works with the command line then?

Comment: @TomMac Now that you've updated your question, you can see flake8 is only complaining about problems in `app`... isn't that what you want?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I notice your `.flake8` file is inside `app` folder. I presume you are starting `flake8` from outside the `app` folder, in other words from the project root.

Move `.flake8` to the project root, and everything's gonna work:

```
mv app/.flake8 .
```

Answer (score 34):

Remove the commas. Lists in these .ini files are simply multi-line lists:

```
[flake8]
exclude =
    migrations
    __pycache__
    manage.py
    settings.py
    env
    .env
```

Comment: Thanks AKX but it doesn't seem to change anything, I'm still getting the errors

Comment: Your directory is also called `env`, not `.env` :)

Comment: Haha I'm trying with env
    .env
    ./env
    env/
    .env/ !

Comment: the documentation for flake8 uses commas https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/configuration.html

Answer (score 8):

It's also possible to exclude via `--exclude` flag of the cli.

```
 --exclude patterns    Comma-separated list of files or directories to
                    exclude. (Default: ['.svn', 'CVS', '.bzr', '.hg',
                    '.git', '__pycache__', '.tox', '.eggs', '*.egg'])
```

note that here it is a comma-separated list, unlike in the flake8 config file

Answer (score 1):

```
flake8 --exclude venv --ignore=E501,F401
```

example exclude folder venv and ignore errors