# Travis CI failing flake8 tests despite flake8 tests passing on local development environment?

Tags: python, docker, travis-ci, flake8

## Background

I am building a project using Django, Docker, Travis CI and Flake8. My flake8 file:

```
[flake8]
max-line-length = 119
exclude =
    migrations,
    __pycache__,
    manage.py,
    settings.py,
    env
```

When I run local flake8 tests using:

```
docker-compose exec app python manage.py test && flake8
```

I receive an ok message with no error messages. My code is good!

## The problem

When I push my code to master which automatically starts Travis CI, the Travis build fails due to the following errors:

```
./project/settings.py:94:80: E501 line too long (91 > 79 characters)
./project/settings.py:97:80: E501 line too long (81 > 79 characters)
./project/settings.py:100:80: E501 line too long (82 > 79 characters)
./project/settings.py:103:80: E501 line too long (83 > 79 characters)
./core/models.py:7:80: E501 line too long (93 > 79 characters)
./core/models.py:13:80: E501 line too long (104 > 79 characters)
./core/migrations/0001_initial.py:18:80: E501 line too long (126 > 79 characters)
The command "docker-compose run app sh -c "python manage.py test && flake8"" exited with 1.
```

My flake8 file specifically states that the max line length is 119 so these errors should not be happening (like they are not when running the test on my local machine).

Does anyone know whats going on?

Comment: is the problem the same as your other problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60865887/exclude-env-directory-from-flake8-tests

Comment: No its a different problem?

Comment: hmmm, could you show the layout of your repository and perhaps a link to it if it's open source?

Comment: if it's this one, it's because you never copy the flake8 configuration into your image: https://github.com/DevelopwithTom/simple_inventory_api/blob/master/Dockerfile (if you rebuild locally you should see the same issue)

Comment: Hi Anthony, sorry for some reason I'm not getting notifications when you comment! It is that repo you're correct. I'm not getting the same issue locally I think because I've set the maximum max-line-length = 119 in the flake8 file

Comment: probably due to either: an out of date build, hot mounting of your current directory.  your dockerfile never does `COPY . .` so your `.flake8` file is never put into the image

Comment: Thats worked great. Thank you. I added COPY . . to my dockerfile instead of the mkdir command. You can make this an answer that I can accept if you like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there wasn't enough information in the question so I went digging into OP's github

this was their dockerfile when the question was asked:

```
FROM python:3.9.0a5-alpine3.10
MAINTAINER Tom Mac

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN apk add --update --no-cache postgresql-client
RUN apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .tmp-build-deps \
    gcc libc-dev linux-headers postgresql-dev
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt
RUN apk del .tmp-build-deps

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./app /app

RUN adduser -D user
USER user
```

their flake8 configuration was at `.flake8` in the root of their repository

since this file was not part of their image (nothing `COPY`d it in), it was not being respected while linting

adding this file into the image (the easiest way being `COPY . .` which adds *everything*) fixes this

---

what I suspect happened:

- in [Exclude .env directory from flake8 tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60865887/exclude-env-directory-from-flake8-tests) it was pointed out that the flake8 configuration was in the wrong place
- OP probably moved the configuration from `app/.flake8` (which *is* in the image listed above)
- OP then either: (1) didn't rebuild the image after doing that or (2) has some type of local mounting setup where `.` is mounted into the container at runtime

either way, rebuilding and adding `COPY . .` should fix this